# How to uninstall Real VNC in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

Well the title almost says it all, I installed Real VNC.

First I downloaded the generic installer 5.2.3 64-bit from [here](http://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/):

Then I used

```
tar -xvf VNC-5.2.3-Linux-x64-ANY.tar.gz
```

to unpack and with

```
sudo ./vncinstall
```

I installed everything.

Now I don't need VNC anymore so I want to uninstall it but I don't know how to do this.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) to avoid the same mistake in the future...  **;-)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There are two ways…

---

**The deb way**

[Download](https://www.realvnc.com/download/get/1716/) the archive with deb files and extract the archive, and yes, I'm sure

```
tar xf VNC-5.2.3-Linux-x64-DEB.tar.gz
```

Install via

```
sudo dpkg -i VNC-Server-5.2.3-Linux-x64.deb VNC-Viewer-5.2.3-Linux-x64.deb
```

And remove the packages. This will also remove the files from the installation via `./vncinstall`

```
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-server
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-viewer
```

---

**The script way**

There is no script to remove the installed files. But you could use this, tested on my own system:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncviewer.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncaddrbook.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncserver-x11.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/Xvnc.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncserver-virtual.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncserver-virtuald.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncserver-x11-serviced.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncpasswd.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vnclicense.1
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/vncinitconfig.1
sudo rm /etc/pam.d/vncserver

sudo rm -r /root/.vnc
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/vnc
sudo rm -r /usr/share/vnc
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/cups/vnc
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/cups/backend/vnc
sudo rm -r /usr/share/vnc
sudo rm -r /etc/vnc

for f in vncviewer vncaddrbook vncserver-x11 vncserver-x11-core Xvnc Xvnc-core \
         vncserverui vncserver-virtual vncserver-virtuald \
         vncserver-x11-serviced vncpasswd vnclicense vnclicensewiz \
         vnclicensehelper vncpipehelper vncinitconfig vncserver; do
    sudo rm "/usr/bin/$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!
Just out of pure interest, how can I check, whether everything was uninstalled/removed completely? I checked whether the files, listed in your script, are still available or not. Is there another way?

Comment: you could use `find / -iname "*vnc*"` but there could be many false positive results.